# Div-Positioning fail and Style-Error because of JS-Sort

Tags: javascript, html, css, sorting

I have a table wich shows products. The table is created by a mysqli_fetch_array($var)

like:

`<tr>    <td>Product-Name</td>   <td>Product-Nr</td>   <td>Price</td>   </tr>`

and for the Details of the product, a div takes place (for xmlhttp), after the first tr, like this:

`<tr>  <td> <div id="det+php"> .... </td>  </tr>`

**PROBLEM1:** To make it viewer-friendly, i used `tr:nth-of-type(even)` to Color the `<tr>`, but since the div is inside a tr, the table is all white.  But the Div-Part should be always white.

is there a command like "dont affect this tr" with the style?

**PROBLEM2** 
Since i use asc/desc sorting in the table, the `<tr>` with the div gets sorted to the top/bottom what is very wrong, the `<tr>` with the div should be ALWAYS! be direct under the product `<tr>`, to display the details there

How can this be solved?

To show what i tried, i made a fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/pt2w3/33/

**Im also open for ideas to solve this a complete other way**

Comment: Why is this a PHP question since no PHP code is shown and PHP is really not affected in solving your problem. In case to try to be helpful, I would suggest not mixing div's and tables. Use div/spans and proper styling to make it tablic, or use pure table (tr, td, etc..)

Comment: php is used to get the data... 
but i have to use a div because of the xmlhttp, it can only be set to a div (.innerhtml=xmlhttp.responseText;).
And it has to be in the table, because of the fixed layout.

Comment: With only div's and spans you can achieve the same look as the table you have shown :)

Comment: But sorting also? How <div> can be sorted in real-time? No refresh or something?

Comment: I don't understand problem 2. You click outside of the table to show the details, so which product should the details appear under?

Comment: the fiddle is only for showing the Display Problem, in real, the ?`<td>  Product-NR</td>` has a function `<Label onclick="doDetail(<php echo $var['articlenr'] ?>)"> NR </Label` and the div's id is `id="det<'php echo $var['articlenr'] ?>"` and the js function sends the xmhlhttp-Response to the div wich has the articlenr like the label you clicked... and this div should be direct under the product-tr

Comment: Also, I guess I don't understand Problem 1 either becuase the colors of the rows are working in firefox and the div is always white.

Comment: this is because of sorting, here, you see http://jsfiddle.net/pt2w3/36/ what i mean...the div-tr gets blue... not the next 1.2 or so...

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If not, why aren't you?